# Docker container can't talk to another container

Tags: docker

I have a docker compose file set up with 3 separate containers (Flask, Nginx and Solr)

After starting up all 3 run successfully but my Flask application can't connect to my Solr instance and when I run:

```
wget -S http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/select
```

I get the error `"Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8983... failed: Connection refused."`

I am fairly new to docker and been around a few different forums looking at this issue but nothing has worked so far. I have tried creating a network also but running into the same issue.

Here is my docker-compose.yml.

```
version: "2.7"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8181:8181"
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/ee1
      - ee1-logs-volume:/var/log/ee1
      - ./:/usr/local/websites/ee1
      - sockets-volume:/tmp
    depends_on:
      - flask
  flask:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-flask
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "./system/start-uwsgi-docker.bash"]
    container_name: flask
    user: root
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/ee1
      - ./ee1config.ini:/opt/ee1config.ini
      - ee1jobs-logs-volume:/var/log/ee1
      - ./:/usr/local/websites/ee1
      - sockets-volume:/tmp
    links:
      - solr
  solr:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-solr
    container_name: solr
    volumes:
      - data:/var/solr
    entrypoint:
    - bash
    - "-c"
    - "precreate-core ee1_1; precreate-core ee1_2; exec solr -f"
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
volumes:
  sockets-volume: {}
  ee1-logs-volume: {}
  data:
```

Comment: `wget -S http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/select` Where are you running this from? From the host or from within a container?

Comment: From within the flask container. I am checking whether the flask instance recognises the above and it doesn't but I can access it via my browser so I know its active.

Comment: `flask` and `solr` have their own localhost's. `solr`s hostname is `solr`.

Comment: So what your saying is I can try connect via http://solr:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/select

Comment: From within any container in your docker compose stack, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Every docker container is - network wise - a separate host with it's own IP.
Traffic to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` will definitely never leave that container.

So what you need to find out is the IP of the server container (solr) you actually want to talk to, then configure the client container (flask) accordingly. This can be done by e.g. `docker inspect`. Be aware that upon container restart the IPs can change. You will want to use something like DNS rather than raw IPs.

Since you use docker compose, each container for a service joins the same network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

For more details check out

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
- https://docs.docker.com/network/